# Outputting the API response to Python console

Tags: python, python-requests

I use an API from Technic company for my project. I need to make a request and get a response and display it in Python console. I wrote the code but it doesn't work. How I can fix it?

```
import requests

def mouser_api_request(keyword):
    mouser_api_key = 'MY_API_KEY'
    version = 'v1'

    url = f'https://api.mouser.com/api/v{version}/search/keyword?apiKey={mouser_api_key}'

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    params = {'keyword': keyword}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

    if response.status_code == 200:
      data = response.json()
      print(data)
    else:
      print('Mouser API request failed')

keyword_to_search = input('Input your keyword ')
mouser_api_request(keyword_to_search)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is modified example (according to their API doc here: https://api.mouser.com/api/docs/ui/index):

```py
import requests


# API doc here: https://api.mouser.com/api/docs/ui/index
def mouser_api_request(keyword):
    mouser_api_key = "MY_API_KEY"
    version = "1"  # <--- change here to "1" (or "1.0")

    url = f"https://api.mouser.com/api/v{version}/search/keyword"

    params = {"apiKey": mouser_api_key}

    # https://api.mouser.com/api/docs/ui/index#/SearchApi/SearchApi_SearchByKeyword
    payload = {
        "SearchByKeywordRequest": {
            "keyword": keyword,  # <--- your keyword
            "records": 0,  # <--- probably should be higher number
            "startingRecord": 0,
            # "searchOptions": "string",
            # "searchWithYourSignUpLanguage": "string",
        }
    }

    response = requests.post(url, params=params, json=payload)  # <--- use .post()

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        print(data)
    else:
        print("Mouser API request failed")


keyword_to_search = input("Input your keyword ")
mouser_api_request(keyword_to_search)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to do:

```py
import json

def mouser_api_request(keyword):
    
    ...
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
      text = response.text
      data = json.loads(text)
      print(data)
    else:
      print('Mouser API request failed')
```

This is due to first extracting the text from the response, which is a raw json text, and then processing it via `json.loads()`